# ¿Cómo insertar registros en dos tablas relacionadas SQL?

Tags: sql

Buenas tardes y un saludo a toda la comunidad, tengo una pregunta.

Tengo dos tablas, tabla *solicitudes* y tabla **equipos**, tengo una relacion de 1 a muchos. Ya que los equipos pueden recibir muchas solicitudes.

La tabla solicitudes contienen los siguientes campos:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`solicitudes` (
  `idsolicitudes` INT NOT NULL,
  `idminiauditorios` INT NOT NULL,
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `idequipos` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre_sala` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `nombre_equipo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `fecha_solicitud` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `hora_inicio_evento` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `fecha_evento_inicio` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `fecha_evento_fin` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `hora_fin_evento` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `detalles_actividad` VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  `equipos_idequipos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsolicitudes`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Y la tabla equipos los siguientes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`equipos` (
  `idequipos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `idsolicitudes` INT NOT NULL,
  `detalles` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idequipos`),
  INDEX `fk_equipos_solicitudes_idx` (`idsolicitudes` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_equipos_solicitudes`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idsolicitudes`)
    REFERENCES `login`.`solicitudes` (`idsolicitudes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

La tabla solicitudes está relacionada a través de la tabla equipos a través de idsolicitudes.

Yo deseo que la tabla equipos tenga previamente almacenados los nombres de los equipos con un campo para descripción y otra para cantidad.

Cuando intento ingresar datos la tabla equipos me da el siguiente error:

> ## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`login`.`miniauditorios`, CONSTRAINT `fk_miniauditorios_solicitudes` FOREIGN KEY (`idsolicitudes`) REFERENCES `solicitudes` (`idsolicitudes`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) Motivado a que no he agregado información en la tabla solicitudes.

¿Cómo puedo llenar los datos de la tabla equipos para poder preestablecer cuales serán los equipos que contendrá la tabla?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo tenes al revés.

Parecería ser que son las solicitudes que deberían estar referenciando a los equipos. Es decir que la foreing key debería setearse en la tabla de solicitudes hacia la tabla de equipos.

Eso te va a permitir tener los equipos cargados sin solicitudes, pero no solicitudes para equipos que no existan o al menos no estén cargados en la tabla de equipos.

La idea de la foreing key es restringir el ingreso de un valor en un campo, si no ese valor no existe previamente en un determinado campo de otra tabla.

Comment: Funciona muy mal una base de dato de por lo menos 6 tablas si no hago ninguna relación?

Me cuesta avanzar por estas benditas relaciones que no me deja luego insertar registros.

Comment: No fa a funcionar mal, pero perdes  por un lado la consistencia de datos que estas reglas ofrecen y por otro el uso de índices cuando se busca por estos campos que hacen que la consulta se resuelva más rápido..